# Update query running slow in stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a query to update the records in database based on certain condition. My query is something like below:

```
    update table1
    set value ='some value'
    where id in ( /*inner query based on joins*/)
```

When I execute this query directly in dbeaver tool, it completes in about 20 sec.
There are about 11million records in the database.

But when I run the same query in stored procedure, it takes about 40 minutes.
Below is how my stored procedure is created:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_query_procedure(input_value varchar)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    AS $$
    DECLARE
    update_query varchar := ' update table1 '
'   set "value" = ''some value'''
'   where id in ('
'   /* inner query */
'   )';
BEGIN
    update_query = replace(update_query, 'replace', input_value);
    EXECUTE update_query;
END;
$$;
```

Why is there a difference in execution time when the query is executed directly and from the stored procedure? How can I debug where the issue is?

Comment: Use auto_explain with `auto_explain.log_nested_statements = on` to find out the execution plan and look for differences.

Comment: A subquery and using IN() is not very fast, you could replace this by using EXITS

Comment: You really need to look at this [Dynamic commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).